# How to get the messages from console.log and sent them to a channel with discord.js

Tags: discord.js, console.log

Is there a way to get messages from console log and send them to a specific discord channel?

I am using **discord.js 12.5.3**

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: that mean when there is a message sent in the console log, the bot can auto send the message to my channel

Comment: Send the same string you log to that channel. Are you struggling with locating where you log or how to send to specific channels?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok i am just wondering if the bot can auto detect if there is any messages that are sent to console log and send them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `console.log()` to log something or an error, use with it `channel.send()` simply.
For example, you want to send to a channel an error that got logged while giving a role for example, you can do:

```js
try {
  // add your code
  } catch (err) {
         console.log(err)
         const embed = new MessageEmbed()
             .setDescription(`${err}`)
         client.channels.cache.get('ID').send({embeds: [embed]})
```

If you wish to send the logged messages of your ready event you can do:

```js
client.on(ready', async () => {
       // Your code here
       console.log('Bot is online')
       client.channels.cache.get('ID').send({content: `Bot is online`})
});
```

It's very simple, messages sent to the console are mostly sent when you use `console.log()` so use `<channel>.send()` with it so it send the message to a channel too.

Also in v12, use `.send('...')` not `.send({content: '...'})`